# Mediaplayer in JAR

Tags: javafx, jar, media-player

This code compile   in Intellij, but it does not work in jar.
Working with `getResourceAsStream()`  or `getResource` doest not solve the problem.

(I have tried out with Image like `Image image = newImage(getClass().getResourceAsStream("image.png");`and it does work)

```
package Sound;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.io.File;

/**
 */
public class TestSound extends Application{

    public TestSound() {
        play();
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        new TestSound().play();
    }
    private void play(){
        String mainsound = "src/res/sound/main.mp3";
        Media i = null;
        i = new Media( new File(mainsound).toURI().toString());
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(i);
        mediaPlayer.play();
        mediaPlayer.setStopTime(new Duration(120000));
        mediaPlayer.setCycleCount(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);
    }
    public static void main (String[] args){
         launch(args);
 }
}
```

EDIT:

```
  Media i = new Media(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(mainsound));
```

wont work, because the constructor need a String.

but also

```
  Media i = new     Media(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(mainsound).toString());
  new MediaPlayer(i).play();
```

does not work.

ofcourse mainsound="res/sound/main.mp3";

After extraction of jar with winrar
I got dictionary of sound with include the
  testsound.class and main.mp3

And another dictionary of res with include main.mp3

Both dictionary are in the same root.

Comment: The path is wrong. There's no way the `src` folder is going to be available at runtime, especially in a jar file. You need to use `getClass().getResource(...)` with the correct path. Check the contents of the jar file you generate by executing `jar tf MyFile.jar` from the command line; make sure you see the mp3 file in the list and note the path it has.

Comment: Maybe see if https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html helps.

Comment: Any reason you a) add `play();` to constructor and `start` method? b) create another instance of `TestSound` in the `start` method?

Comment: @James_D yes, the .mp3 is in Jar and the file path is C:Users/Max/Desktop/TestSound/res/sound/main.mp3                                              does it mean, if i change the path of the jar. i have to the change the path of ressource too?

Comment: No, you need the path of the mp3 *in the jar file*, not in your source or resource folder. Probably, depending on the configuration of your IDE, it will so to `/sound/main.mp3`, so you could use `getClass().getResource("/sound/main.mp3");`, but I don't know how you have configured your IDE to build the jar file. What happens if you list the jar contents as I suggested in my previous comment?

Comment: i edited my question

Comment: Why do you keep putting `src` in there? The **source folder is not available at runtime and is not included in the jar file**. Can you show what you get when you list the contents of the jar file? Did you try the suggestion in my previous comment?

Comment: i edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getClass().getResource("res/sound/main.mp3")` is going to look for a resource named `res/sound/main.mp3` relative to the current class. Since your class is in the `sound` package, it's effectively going to look for `/sound/res/sound/main.mp3`, which is not where the resource is located in your jar.

If the list of entries in the jar file is showing

```
/sound/main.mp3
```

then the following should work:

```
String mediaURL = getClass().getResource("/sound/main.mp3").toExternalForm();
// for debugging:
System.out.println(mediaURL);

Media i = new Media(mediaURL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `getClass ().getResource (...)` it would be ideal to use it like

```
Media m = new Media ("/myMedia.mp3");//if the media exists in default package
```

or

```
Media m = new Media ("/mypackage/myMedia.mp3");//if the media exists in mypackage
```

Comment: The OP wants to run the application bundled as a jar file though. How would this work if the media file is inside the jar?

Comment: Does not work: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: uri.getScheme() == null! uri == '/greeting.wav'